# Spring Boot 2x. Rest api. Convert failed String to Date

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime-format

I pass to api object from client

```
@ApiModel(value = "EMail", description = "Model with property for sending email")
@Document(collection = "email")
public class EMail extends Letter {

@ApiModelProperty(value = "Date send email")
private Date sendEmail;

public Date getSendEmail() {
    return sendEmail;
}

public void setSendEmail(Date sendEmail) {
    this.sendEmail = sendEmail;
}
```

Here my controller

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Save email")
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveEmail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveEmail(EMail eMail){
    eMailService.saveEmail(eMail);
}
```

When i pass Email to api i get error that spring boot can't convert String to Date,although date in format ISO Date_Time (default in spring boot).
Here is exception

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '2018-08-03T07:38:17.856+0000'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2018-08-03T07:38:17.856+0000]","objectName":"EMail","field":"sendEmail","rejectedValue":"2018-08-03T07:38:17.856+0000","bindingFailure":true,"code":"typeMismatch"}],"message":"Validation failed for object='EMail'. Error count: 1","path":"/api/saveEmail"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update your EMail model with `@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat`

```
@ApiModel(value = "EMail", description = "Model with property for sending email")
@Document(collection = "email")
public class EMail extends Letter {

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) 
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Date send email")
    private Date sendEmail;

    public Date getSendEmail() {
        return sendEmail;
    }

    public void setSendEmail(Date sendEmail) {
        this.sendEmail = sendEmail;
    }
}
```

This will apply the correct binding for query and path parameters.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i get date without time, do your know how save with time?

Comment: You will need to set the iso to DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME. You may also need to encode the URL for example
2018-08-03T07:38:17.856+0000 would become 
2018-08-03T07:38:17.856%2B00:00. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME call the same error. This settings install by default in spring boot. And encode same not working